# Android AutoComplete TextView

Tags: android

Hi
 i have using a autocomplete textview,how can i specify the direction of pop up list?

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that is supported in [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), suggest extending AutoCompleteTextView and adding orientation attribute.